# How do I make a function wait until a database connection is established before continuing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, module

Probably worded poorly, I understand async/promises/callbacks.

What I'm trying to do is create a module which can be required (`database.js`), which I can then call methods such as `database.insert()` and `database.read()`.

So here is my code:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
const client = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGO_URI);

var db, queue;

client.connect().then(e => {
    console.log('connected to database');

    db = client.db('filemanager');
    queue = db.collection('queue');
});

function insert (data, cb) {
    queue.insertOne(data)
        .then(res => {cb()})
}

module.exports = {
    insert: insert,
}
```

The question is: How do I make it so when `database.insert()` is called, it will process instantly if db and queue are already defined, but if they aren't it will wait until they are, then will continue processing like normal?

Comment: Do you know async/await syntax? I think it is more handy in your situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign the result of a promise to a variable, and you can call `then` on it later. For example:

```js
const queuePromise = client.connect().then(e => {
    console.log('connected to database');

    const db = client.db('filemanager');
    const queue = db.collection('queue');

    return queue;
});
```

Now you have a variable called `queuePromise` that is a Promise that resolves to a `db.collection` object. Then you can use that promise like this

```js
queuePromise.then((queue) => {
    // do something with the queue
});
```

So you can have a function like this

```js
const insert = (data, callback) => {
    queuePromise.then((queue) => {
        queue.insertOne(data).then(callback);
    });
};
```

Or even better, don't use the callback pattern and go like this

```js
const insert = (data) => {
    return queuePromise.then((queue) => {
        return queue.insertOne(data);
    });
};

// use the callback in a `then` after calling `insert`
insert(data).then(callback);
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks good but I have a few questions if you dont mind: 1. So in the first snippet, is the same promise that connect() returns assigned to queuePromise, even though you call .then at the end? 2. In the second snippet, did you mean to write queuePromise.then()? 3. So once a promise is resolved, I can can still call .then() on it, and it will just return the value instantly? 4. In example 4, how come it returns the insertOne promise, and not the result of queuePromise, because it gets returned inside queuePromise.then()?

Comment: @stackers For your questions 1, 3 and 4, you'll want to have a look at [how the `.then()` method works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then). Such chaining is [the core principle of promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572).

Comment: @stackers 1. Yes, you can chain promises together and call `.then()`, `.catch()`, or `.finally()` as many times as you want. 2. Whoops, fixed. 3. Yep :) 4. `return queue.insertOne(data)` returns a value, which means that the `queuePromise.then()` part is going to return a promise that resolves to that same value. Then the `insert` function will return that promise. So `insert` returns a promise that resolves to the result of the `insertOne` function. On the very last line, we can use that promise and call `.then()` on it again with whatever callback we want.